# SQL "IN" statement in Linq conversion

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I have a SQL Query and I wanted to convert into LINQ can you please help to do this.

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.ProductName FROM tblProducts p
WHERE p.ProductID IN (SELECT s.ProductID FROM tblStock s WHERE s.BarCode = 2222)
```

In this case BarCode is a null able type.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).aspx) to translate to 'IN':

```
tblProducts.Where(p => tblStock.Where(ts => ts.BarCode == 2222)
                               .Select(ts => ts.ProductId)
                               .Contains(p.ProductID))
           .Select(p => new {p.ProductID, p.ProductName});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `join` instead of `in`:

```
var result = tblProducts
.Join 
(
tblStock.Where(s => s.BarCode = 2222),
p => p.ProductID,
s => s.ProductID,
(p, s) => new { ProductID = p.ProductID, ProductName = p.ProductName }
);
```

Depending on your data and needs, you could also add `.Distinct()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be written as an inner join for efficiency.  In Linq:

```
var myQuery = from p in myContext.tblProducts
                 join s in myContext.tblStock on p.ProductID equals s.ProductID
                    where s.BarCode = 2222
                       select new { ProductID = p.ProductID, ProductName = p.ProductName };

foreach(var product in myQuery)
{
   // do stuff
}
```